# How to draw this graph using R or ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have some data like this:

```
6/22/2013 16:39
6/23/2013 16:42
6/23/2013 17:41
6/24/2013 17:49
6/24/2013 14:06
6/24/2013 14:16
```

These are just some times in different days. I want something like this:
[image]

How can I implement this? Thanks.

Comment: perhaps you could google it first

Comment: Make sure your data is of the correct class, then plot as normal with `ggplot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x=date,y=time))+geom_point()
```